# Why does "每天我都得吃药 Měitiān wǒ dū dé chī yào" include "dū"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

From my understanding 每天我都得吃药 (Měitiān wǒ dū dé chī yào)

都 = All, both, entirely etc.

So my understanding of the English translation would be "Everyday I have to take medicine"

Also I know "得" in this case may mean "must" like dĕi. But I don't see how "都" fits in.

Comment: Instead of 每天我都得吃药, I'd say 我每天都得吃药.

Comment: "得" in this case does mean "must", and its pinyin is dĕi, not dé

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 每天我都得吃药。
> Měitiān wǒ **dōu děi** chī yào
> Every day I must take medicine.

Firstly, let's straighten out the pinyin: it's not 都 (dū), which is used in 首都 = "capital" and 成都 = "Chengdu" (a city name), but 都 (dōu) = "all".  It's not 得 (dé) = "to obtain", it's 得 (děi) = "must" (as you point out).

> 每天我都……
> Měitiān wǒ dōu...
> Every day I...

The 都 here applies to 每天, and basically implies there are no days in which it is not true.  I feel like it's somewhat more common to encounter the word order:

> 我每天都……
> Wǒ měitiān dōu...
> Every day I...

---

> [image: Google Translate screenshot]

I guess the errors come from Google Translate; the pinyin for 都 and 得 here is just plain wrong.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! 多谢!

Answer (score 2):

都 in here means "whole/entirely". It implies the event has repeated regularly over a stretch of time/days, which can be seen as a period and as a whole. So  "每天都" means "each of these days" rather than simply "every day".

The correct pronunciation of "都得" is "dōu děi".

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, `都` pronounces `dōu` and you can't remove it.

Here are a few other similar sentences:

1. `每天我都要吃药`
2. `每天我都会吃药`

The two above sentences are similar, but they don't contain `得`, so the person who speaks them is not unhappy about taking medicine, compared to the one in your question.

3. `那段时间，他每天都会给我打电话` He used to call me every day during that period.

You can't remove `都` because it means you have to do this *daily*, and there is no exception. However, if there are a few exceptions, you may want to say:

- `我几乎每天都得吃药`

I have to take medicine every day, but with a few exceptions (not particularly specified)

- `我每天都得吃药，除非哪天我的胃特别不舒服`

I have to take medicine every day unless that day my stomach feels very uncomfortable.

Comment: Good feedback, 我很感激!